# Laravel image validation from controller not working

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to create a validator to my form input, to only accept images. I've searched here on stack and other forums, but all the answers that i got didn't work for me.. Most of the answers where syntax erros of the lack of enctype="multipart/form-data".. but that is not the case here, aparently.. Here is my form and my controller:

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('file')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="input-group hdtuto control-group lst increment" >
   
        <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
   
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
   
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" style="width: 100px !important"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i>Add</button>
   
        </div>
   
    </div>
   
    <div class="clone hide">
   
        <div class="hdtuto control-group lst input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
   
            <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
   
            <div class="input-group-btn"> 
   
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="button" style="width: 100px !important"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
   
            </div>
   
        </div>
   
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>

</form>

<?php
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\File;

class FileController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('create');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'filenames' => 'mimetypes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            'filenames.*' => 'required'
          ],$messages = [
            'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            'mimes' => 'Apenas jpeg, png, png são permitidos.'
    ]
    );

    $files = [];
    if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
     {
        foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
        {
            $name = time().rand(1,100).'.'.$file->extension();
            $file->move(public_path('files'), $name);  
            $files[] = $name;  
        }
     }

     $file= new File();
     $file->filenames = $files;
     $file->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Data Your files has been successfully added');
}
}
```

I've tried to change the validation to this: `'mimes:jpeg,png |max:4096, required',`  , but still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
$rules = array(
     'filenames' => 'required|array',
     'filenames.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg'
);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Would you care to explain what was the difference of your code from mine? Just the order or the syntax.. or both ?

Comment: You are passing array image but you are checking mimes of array instead of items. 
Ps: If your code worked, please sign my answer as answer